# XPath. How to find first occurence of ancestor

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to select first occurence of an ancestor with a text attribute. For example given the xml below I need to select only nodes with a comment next.

```
<root>
<referenceNode name="att">
    <a>
        <b>
            <referenceNode name="att">
                <a>
                    <b>
                        <referenceNode name="att"> <!-- OK -->
                        </referenceNode>
                    </b>
                    <referenceNode name="att"> <!-- OK -->
                    </referenceNode>
                </a>            
            </referenceNode>
        </b>
        <referenceNode name="att"> <!-- OK -->
        </referenceNode>
    </a>
</referenceNode>
```

I'm trying to select  without a  child with this:

```
//referenceNode[@name='att' and not(child::referenceNode)]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `referenceNode` is never a child of `referenceNode`, it's a **descendant**.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand xpath, you should swap in `descendants` for `child`, as none of the `referenceNode`s are direct children of another one.

Comment: Thank you, this works: //referenceNode[not(descendant::referenceNode)]